# Lutris won't run

Tags: software-installation, lutris

just installing `lutris`, the the first time i ran it it went straight into a crash message and since then it won't run at all, even after a remove and reinstall. It's present in my apps but clicking it does nothing. I couldn't see any processes for it when i ran `top`. Tried using the submit issue command and this was the result if that helps. It was also the result of the `lutris -d` command. I'm a complete noob at linux (don't even know what the -d command does) but what's going on?

```
lutris --submit-issue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/games/lutris", line 54, in <module>
    from lutris.gui.application import Application  # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/gui/application.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .lutriswindow import LutrisWindow
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/gui/lutriswindow.py", line 26, in <module>
    from lutris.gui.widgets.sidebar import LutrisSidebar
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/gui/widgets/sidebar.py", line 6, in <module>
    from lutris import platforms, runners, services
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/platforms.py", line 19, in <module>
    _init_platforms()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/platforms.py", line 14, in _init_platforms
    runner = runners.import_runner(runner_name)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/runners/wine.py", line 229, in __init__
    "default": dxvk.DXVKManager().version,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/wine/dxvk.py", line 56, in version
    return self.versions[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/wine/dxvk.py", line 45, in versions
    self._versions = self.load_dxvk_versions()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/wine/dxvk.py", line 65, in load_dxvk_versions
    with open(versions_path, "r") as dxvk_version_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/indraneelan/.local/share/lutris/runtime/dxvk/dxvk_versions.json'
```

i followed these steps linuxconfig.org/… mainly: `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lutris-team/lutris` then: `$ sudo apt update $ sudo apt install lutris`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies, I found the answer on a lutris forum. Apparently it's a known bug with this version of Lutris, and a moderator on there posted this solution in a couple of the threads raising the issue.

```
wget https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/538903130704838656/796102070825779250/dxvk_versions.json -P $HOME/.local/share/lutris/runtime/dxvk
```

they said it'll be fixed properly in the next release.